# Get build and changeset number from Team Foundation Server

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, tfs

I have been given a task to use the TFS API in order to check which build has which changeset number, after deployment. I haven't worked with TFS before, so mainly I've been trying to Google things, to find the answer. I've been at it for 2 days now, so I'm hoping someone can nudge me in the right direction...

Here is what I have done so far:

```
Uri collectionUri = new Uri("mytfs/tfs/");
var server = TfsConfigurationServerFactory.GetConfigurationServer(collectionUri);
server.Authenticate();
server.EnsureAuthenticated();
var service = server.GetService<TswaClientHyperlinkService>();
var projectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("mytfs/tfs/collection"));
var cssService = projectCollection.GetService<ICommonStructureService3>();
var project = cssService.GetProjectFromName("project");

WorkItemStore workItemStore = projectCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
WorkItemCollection workItemCollection = workItemStore.Query("SELECT * FROM WorkItems");
```

So in the workItemCollection object, I tried a few queries, but it seems it doesn't allow me to change database, use joins etc. just a simple select/from statement.

Am I on the right track - is this how I should be getting build and changeset number?? If yes, where can I see what tables I need to query?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you're thinking of this as a database. It's not a database. It's an object model that allows you to programmatically access various aspects of TFS through a well-defined API.

Work item queries are not SQL, they are WIQL (*work item query language*). The work item object will definitely have a link to the associated changeset, but it won't have a link to a build. Some work item types have a field for "fixed in" that will be automatically updated with the build, but not all of them, so it's not necessarily reliable.

To find particular builds, you'll need to use the `IBuildServer` service and search for a build spec.